# how to set font bold and underline by coding?

Tags: fonts, codenameone

I am changing the font of Label by using coding and i want to set both bold and underline on the font , how to do it?
I am using the following codes

```
Font fnt = Font.createTrueTypeFont("abc.ttf", "abc.ttf").
           derive(4, Font.STYLE_BOLD);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the bold Font and text decoration for the Label with the Style class.  For example :

```
Font fnt = Font.createTrueTypeFont("abc.ttf", "abc.ttf").
       derive(4, Font.STYLE_BOLD);
/* 
*  I set up all styles in this case (Unselected,Selected,Pressed,Disabled),     
*  but btw you can edit each style independantly (getUnslectedStyle(),etc...)
*/
myLabel.getAllStyles().setFont(fnt);       //Font Selected
myLabel.getAllStyles().setUnderline(true); //Text decoration enabled
```

Comment: Correct. I would also mention that the TTF creation is incorrect and will fail on the device, also the font weight is mostly meaningless in this case as the weight is derived from the ttf e.g. roboto-bold. The right way to load fonts from code is discussed in depth in the basics section of the developer guide